# Simple DOM attribute matching in Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Using Google Tag Manager, I'm able to use pre-defined variables like `Click Classes`, `Click ID` to match the `class` and `id` attributes of DOM element But what about something like this below,

`<div data-user_tag="interested-in-service"></div>`

Which GTM feature am i supposed to use to match custom attributes like `data-user_tag` above?

I've tried using Custom Javascript but i'm unable to get the parameters right to access these attributes.

couldn't find a particular example to help me in GTM documentation

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Go to variables, click "new", select "DOM Selector Element. Set to method "CSS selector", enter the selector (tricky part, see below) and set attribute name to "data-user_tag":

[image: Screenshot of Variable Configuration]

The problem is of course that the selector in this case does not (necessarily) address a unique element. If you have multiple divs this variable will return  only the first div with the data-user_tag (actually since attribute name is set it will return the value of the data-user_tag, not the element itself).